# When Unhandled Exception occurs, i want to show some Other view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, exception

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
     NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleExceptions);
 }

static void HandleExceptions(NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"The app has encountered an unhandled exception: %@", [exception debugDescription]);
    NSLog(@"%@",exception.reason);

    NSLog(@"%@",exception.userInfo);

    NSLog(@"%@",exception.name);
}
```

After HandleExceptions is called my app closes.
But I want to show the user a view that says "Something went wrong. Try again later" and I want to post that error to my server.

Comment: You could use `@try {} catch() {}` then. However, **exceptions were not invented to handle recoverable errors and general program flow control.** If an exception is thrown, your program has encountered an **irrecoverable internal inconsistency** and the only sensible thing to do is exiting. So, handle non-fatal errors differently (if this is related to a webservice, then validate/sanitize/filter/parse the response data instead of trusting it blindly. That's cleaner.)

Comment: where i need to use try catch block

Comment: At present i am using it in every method in all classes which seems not  a gud idea

Comment: No, it's certainly not a good idea. How about using **control flow statements** instead for doing control flow? `if`, `else` and `switch` are all beautiful core language features.

Comment: So,no need to Use try catch blocks in all classes and methods.so when app is developemnt v can fix the crashes by seeing the exception in console area. but for any reason when the app is in the store if app is crashed i want post to my sever and want to show another view As i satted in the qusetion, is it possible /

Comment: @siva, when an unhandled exception occurs, there is a bug in your code. You don't fix this by showing some view controller. You fix it by fixing the bug in your code.

Comment: @gnasher729 k,then i was handling the exceptions by keeping try catch block in every class and in every method, if it's not the good way then how to handle them in a simple way